# Deadlock possible without mutual exclusion?

Tags: multithreading, deadlock, computer-science-theory

We always hear that one of the necessary conditions for deadlock is mutual exclusion, only one thread may hold the lock at a time.

However, am I wrong to think it is possible for a non-mutex lock to cause deadlock?

Consider the simple case of a semaphore that allows a max of two threads to hold it.  Suppose we have two 2-semaphores, A and B. Suppose we have 4 process, process A1, A2, B1, and B2.

Suppose process A1 and A2 each grab semaphore A, and process B1 and B2 grab semaphore B.  If we reach a point where A1 and A2 both want semaphore B, and process B1 and B2 both want semaphore A, each without giving up their current lock, there will be a deadlock because the semaphore can only be held by two processes.  But the semaphore allows two processes to hold it, so it's not mutually exclusive!

Could someone explain if this is either incorrect reasoning, or if my interpretation of mutual exclusion is wrong?

Comment: Deadlocking on semaphores is certainly possible, yes.

Comment: You are correct that the situation you describe can result in deadlock. Your interpretation of mutual exclusion is not wrong, but your assertion that mutual exclusion is required for deadlock *is* wrong. You just need some type of exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the scenario you describe leads to deadlock using counting semaphores.
The mutual exclusion condition, taken from

> Abraham Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin, and Greg Gagne. 2008. Operating System Concepts (7th ed.). Wiley Publishing.

says:

> At least one resource must be held in a nonsharable
>   mode; that is, only one process at a time can use the resource. If another
>   process requests that resource, the requesting process must be delayed
>   until the resource has been released.

The resolution of the seeming contradiction is that as the counting semaphore reaches the value `1`, it (or the resource it guards) effectively becomes nonshareable, so from that moment on the well-known conditions apply.
To put it differently, you started examining the system a bit too early.